# How to remove add to compare and price tags(special price and regular price)

Tags: layout, magento, magento-1.4

I want to remove the price tags special price and regular price but retain the prices and also I don't want "add to compare" to be displayed.

So how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you're making a custom theme...

For the "Add to Compare" links simply delete the relevant lines from `template/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml` and `template/catalog/product/list.phtml` files in your theme. If you see any other links, identify their file with [template path hints](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/template-path-hints-tutorial-video/).

Pretty much all the price stuff is handled in the file `template/catalog/product/price.html`.

Comment: Congrats Atif. Whenever you ask a question could you please click the checkmark next to the answer you're happiest with? It helps the site and other visitors too (as well as awarding points to me!)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want something removed visually you can always override the css and make the elements disappear to the visitor.